# Android studio 2.1.1 doesn't recognise stdio.h but runs it fine

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio-2.1

There are similar questions on the site, but most of them are from before Android Studio 2.1 and apparently that seems to have fixed it for everyone else except me.

I'm using Android `Studio 2.1.1, JDK 1.8, NDK 1.2 rc1, gradle-experimental 0.7.0 alpha4` plugin, but I'm still having problems with Android Studio refusing to recognise any C library functions like `stdio.h, jni.h`, and so forth.

The problem is that header declarations like `#include <stdio.h>` all have the header's name in the error colours, and when I mouse over, the only explanation it offers is "cannot find stdio.h" for example. Then of course stuff like printf and system all show up in error colours

However, it runs perfectly fine with the C code. It's not like the greatest impediment, but I would love to actually use Android Studio's features rather than having to guess if I'm writing the correct code.

Comment: What are the specific errors you are seeing when you say "refusing to recognize any C library functions"?

Comment: My header declarations like "#include <stdio.h>" all have the header's name in the error colours, and when I mouse over, the only explanation it offers is "cannot find stdio.h" for example. Then of course stuff like printf and system all show up in error colours

Comment: Broke up the wall of text, added the specific errors from comment into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that in my app's build.gradle file, I had the NDK settings in the defaultConfig object instead of directly under android.ndk, which caused the issue. So do doublecheck your build.gradle files!

For reference, the fixed build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "meow"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.pro'))
            }
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName "mao"
            ldLibs.add("log")
        }
    }
}
```